# SPSS modeller student activation not working

Tags: spss-modeler

While trying to activate SPSS Modeller student activation receiving the below error, irrespective of clearing cookies or trying from different laptop same issue.

Another IBMid has already been used with this application. Please clear your browser's cache prior to logging in with a new IBMid.